# Java SWT - Creating a new window from other class

Tags: java, swt, jface

Today I wanted to create a simple Java SWT GUI Application using Eclipse, but for better clarity I wanted to have every sub-window in a different class. Since I am very new to Java Programming, is there a way to make a different class do its thing just by calling a method? I looked everywhere on the internet, but couldn't find what I was looking for...

Here's what I have so far

```
Button foo = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
foo.setText("Edit");
foo.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event e) {
        switch (e.type) {
            case SWT.Selection:
                // Call the other Class file here
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. I wouldn't call it "calling a class" though, rather "opening another window" in SWT terms.

You simply wrap a `Shell` in your other class, then call the `open()` API from "outside".

If you want to **edit** something, you could even [create wizards](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseWizards/article.html).

---

There are many ways to do what you want to do, I simply chose one of the simple versions. But this is *not* the only way to do it. Wait for [Baz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1449199/baz) to answer, he'll come along with another cool example. ;)

I would recommend you read the `Shell`'s javadoc, too.

**Example:**

**ShellTest.class** (run this as Java Application)

```
/**
 * 
 * @author ggrec
 *
 */
public class ShellTest
{

    // ==================== 2. Instance Fields ============================

    private AnotherShell anotherShell;


    // ==================== 3. Static Methods =============================

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        new ShellTest();
    }


    // ==================== 4. Constructors ===============================

    private ShellTest()
    {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        anotherShell = new AnotherShell();

        createContents(shell);

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if ( !display.readAndDispatch() )
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }


    // ==================== 5. Creators ===================================

    private void createContents(final Composite parent)
    {
        final Button buttonOpen = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
        buttonOpen.setText("Open");

        buttonOpen.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
        {
            @Override public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e)
            {
                anotherShell.open();
            }
        });

        final Button buttonClose = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
        buttonClose.setText("Close");

        buttonClose.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
        {
            @Override public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e)
            {
                anotherShell.close();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**AnotherShell.class** (this would be your "other class")

```
/**
 * 
 * @author ggrec
 *
 */
public class AnotherShell
{

    // ==================== 2. Instance Fields ============================

    private Shell shell;


    // ==================== 4. Constructors ===============================

    public AnotherShell()
    {
        shell = new Shell(Display.getCurrent());
    }


    // ==================== 6. Action Methods =============================

    public void open()
    {
        shell.open();
    }

    public void close()
    {
               // Don't call shell.close(), because then
               // you'll have to re-create it
        shell.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. Correct answer, unfortunately I can't upvote so far .__.